Can I reduce an exhaust duct to pass through a wall?
I have a F6PH48DS1 which is a Milano 48” hood (max 1000 CFM). Requires 8” pipe. I have about 9 feet of 8” pipe before reducing to 6” to exit side wall. Is that an issue?

Well, it's 100.53 square inches of duct cross sectional area reduced to 56.55 square inches of duct cross sectional area, so it will certainly reduce the flow, and making a bigger hole in the wall will maintain it. See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/270485/18078 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/258337/18078 on the same subject.

What makes you think the distance from the fan negates the duct size requirement? I find that an odd suggestion since resistance increases with duct length, making the impact of reduction more significant.
